# VBA - Strange Combobox/Listbox behaviour

Tags: vba, excel

The following code is a part of a bigger program to gather up a set of production orders that tracks movements, which need to be posted in SAP. 
This particular routine is straightforward, it simply collects orders, puts them in an array and puts the list in a combo box.

The problem I'm having is that if I use an array as an approach, the combo box populates as expected, no errors whatsoever, except that the list is there, but invisible. The option, if clicked, will come up correctly, otherwise.

Alternatively, if I do the same thing with the AddItem method, things are visible.

I've observed the same behaviour with listboxes, the items in them will populate, but be invisible, if I try it with an array, but are visible with an addItem approach. I've tested the code with both methods, reset Excel and my computer, and tried to figure out if it's some property I've clicked by accident, but nothing jumps out.

Code is below for reference

Thank you in advance.

```
   Private Sub POs_for_SAP()

    'this routine is going to create the list of POs and populate the combo box with them

    Dim lstcl As Variant, cell As Range, arr_po() As Variant, x As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Staging")

    lstcl = .Range("B10000").End(xlUp).row

    'UserForm12.cboPOSAP.Clear

    For Each cell In .Range("B4:B" & lstcl)

        If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 7)) Then

            'UserForm12.cboPOSAP.AddItem cell

            ReDim Preserve arr_po(x)
            Set arr_po(x) = cell
            x = x + 1

        End If

    Next

    End With

    With UserForm12.cboPOSAP

            .Clear
            .List = arr_po()
            .Style = fmStyleDropDownList

        End With

    UserForm12.Show

    End Sub
```

Comment: Whenever I experience quirky behavoir like this,I clean the workbook using [VBA Cleaner & Compressor for Excel, PowerPoint & Word](http://www.spreadsheet1.com/vba-project-code-cleaner-for-access-excel-powerpoint-word.html).  After repeated use and code modifications, Workbooks get bloated and strange things happen.

Comment: @ThomasInzina, with as much coding and testing as I've done with this file, this might well be it...thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: the comboBox has a setting for column width. it may be zero

Comment: @jsotola, changed it to 1, but it makes no difference

Comment: Set arr_po(x) = cell   ,  there not need "Set".  Only  arr_po(x) = cell

Comment: changed it to `1` what?

Comment: go into form designer, right click the combobox and choose properties .... `boundColumn : 2` .... `columnCount : 2` .... `columnWidth : 1cm;1cm` .... `controlSource : =sheet1!a3` .... `rowSource : =sheet1!d1:e7`    on blank Sheet1  fill some data in D1:E7, then run the userform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Array no need set statement.

```
Private Sub POs_for_SAP()

    'this routine is going to create the list of POs and populate the combo box with them

    Dim lstcl As Variant, cell As Range, arr_po() As Variant, x As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Staging")

    lstcl = .Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row

    'UserForm12.cboPOSAP.Clear

    For Each cell In .Range("B4:B" & lstcl)

        If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 7)) Then

            'UserForm12.cboPOSAP.AddItem cell

            ReDim Preserve arr_po(x)
            arr_po(x) = cell '<~~~no need set
            x = x + 1

        End If

    Next

    End With

    With UserForm12.cboPOSAP

            .Clear
            .List = arr_po()
            .Style = fmStyleDropDownList

        End With

    UserForm12.Show

    End Sub
```